# Не работает move_uploaded_file выдает ошибку 32767

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php7, php.ini

Я уже изменял настройки php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize=5M 
post_max_size=10M
```

Файлы максимальным весом до 5мб

С файлами до 2мб работает нормально

Время выделяемое на загрузку файла не менял так как тестирую на лок хосте и 1 минуты более чем хвататет

(У меня на wamp64 не знаю почему установлено 3 версии php везде менял настройки)

Какие еще настройки и где поменять надо?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все разобрался просто в WmapSerwer что я использую php.ini 
Который он использует находился не в каталоге с php
а в bin\apache\apache2.4.27\bin